# cakephp find and order an array

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a site develop in cakephp 2.0.
I have three tables:

- Activity,
- ActivityIngredients
- ActivityImageIngredients.

Activity has one ActivityIngredients

Activity has one ActivityImageIngredients.

I make a query in my controller where I search some Activity with recursive 1 (in this table there is the field created) and I want to print into my page all result of ActivityIngredients, ActivityImageIngredients in order of creation of the activity.
When I print the array return me first ActivityIngredients in order and after   in order. But I want that if anc ActivityImageIngredients has created first of  ActivityIngredients it be before It. Because there is two separate array I think. The query is a simple find :

```
   $conditions = array('Activity.user_id' => $id ); 
$activity = $this->User->Activity->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)); 
$this->set('activity', $activity);
```

User has many actuvuty order by created
with a condition of other field and I print result into my view in this mode:

```
 <?php
 //var_dump($activity);
 foreach ($activity as $act) {

?>
    <div class="line-cnt"><div class="line">
    </div>
</div>
<h2>Attività</h2>
<div class="table">
    <div>
        <div>Activity created</div><div><?php echo $act['Activity']['created']; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Actions text</div><div><?php echo $act['Action']['text']; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>ActivityIngredient ingredient_id</div><div><?php
        if (isset($act['ActivityImageIngredients']['IngredientAlias']['alias'])){
            echo $act['ActivityImageIngredients']['IngredientAlias']['alias'];
        }
        if (isset($act['ActivityIngredients']['IngredientAlias']['alias'])){
            echo $act['ActivityIngredients']['IngredientAlias']['alias']; 
        }
        ?>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to merge array ActivityImageIngredients and ActivityIngredients and order by created of its Activity is possible?

Comment: Is the initial "query" coming from SQL? If so, it might be more appropriate to post that part of the code as it might lead to a solution. Otherwise, can you post the array structures?

Comment: What query you used in your controller?

Comment: $conditions = array('Activity.user_id' => $id );
  $activity = $this->User->Activity->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
  $this->set('activity', $activity);

Comment: this is my query, User has many activity order by created

Comment: At the top you mentioned: `ActivityIngredientsImage` and below you mentioned `ActivityImageIngredients`?? confusing.. It is better to show models definition and the result you want.

Comment: My error sorry I have correct that :)

Comment: Your question is very unclear... what did you meant by " When I print the array return me first ActivityIngredients in order and after in order." is the order in var_dup the problem ?

Comment: Your models are named incorrectly. A model called `ActivityIngredients` is a HABTM between `Activities` and `Ingredients`